# JMeter simple BeanShell PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter BeanShell PreProcessor function.

For a test I'm trying to print sample URL address.
From the tutorial I have the follownig code:

```
org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

String currentURL = SampleResult.getUrlAsString();
print(currentURL)
```

But I get error "Attempt to resolve method: getUrlAsString() on undefined variable", how to define this variable first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the SampleResult does not exist.

You need to use prev as per this doc:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor

Which references this javadoc:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getUrlAsString--

Answer (score 0):

1. Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting in JMeter tests. So consider migrating to Groovy as soon as possible.
2. If you are using a [PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) it means that you don't have any SampleResult as sampler has not been yet executed. So you need to use `sampler` shorthand which is resolved into [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) like:

   ```
   sampler.getUrl() as String
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Get Current Sampler URL]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)